# Why is 吏 (lì) pronounced differently to 史 (shǐ) and 使 (shǐ)?

Tags: characters, etymology, pronunciation

The pronunciation of 吏 (lì) is frustratingly hard to remember since it's different to two similar-looking characters 史 (shǐ) and 使 (shǐ).  Sometimes learning the etymology, and the reason why a character is pronounced a certain way, can make it easier to remember how to pronounce.  Googling gave me [this](http://qiyuan.chaziwang.com/etymology-9848.html), but I didn't immediately find anything about pronunciation.

**Question**: Why is 吏 (lì) pronounced differently to 史 (shǐ) and 使 (shǐ)?

Answer (score 13):

Let us look at the reconstructions (specifically, at Baxter-Sagart):

- 吏 (lì) 'officer' is **[r]əʔ-s**;
- 史 (shǐ) 'scribe' is **s-rəʔ**;
- 使 (shǐ) 'to send, to cause' is **s-rəʔ**;
- 使 (shì) 'to be sent as an envoy; envoy' is **s-rəʔ-s**.

I will append also the probably basic etymon, even though it is written with an unrelated character:

- 理 (lǐ) 'envoy' is **m(ə).rəʔ** (or probably just **rəʔ** for this word).

The relation between all the words is clear:

1. we have a basic root **rəʔ** 'to serve' (which, per Schuessler, is the same as 理 'to regulate, to administer'; Baxter-Sagart p. 144),
2. from which we get 吏 'officer' **rəʔ-s** with the ordinary
   nominalizing suffix **-s**,
3. with the valency-increasing prefix **s-** we move to 使 'to send, to
   cause' **s-rəʔ**,
4. and finally nominalize the latter as 使 'envoy' **s-rəʔ-s** ('one who
   is sent').

(The verbal meaning for 使 'to be sent as an envoy' **s-rəʔ-s** seems to be a later development when the Old Chinese morphology alrealy broke up at it became possible to just fluidly change parts of speech, per Schuessler p. 350; same for 史 'scribe' **s-rəʔ**, which looks like a direct change of parts of speech from 使 'to send, to cause, to employ' **s-rəʔ**).

From these on, the current pronunciations are all directly derivable. Thus, 吏 actually *maintains* the original consonant the best of all; all the rest in the group use the valency-inclreasing **s-** prefix and thus obtain the initial **s-r-** cluster, which is quite expectedly simplified to a retroflex version of [s], that is, [ʂ].

Answer (score 2):

I'm entirely unqualified to talk about phonology, but from I can tell, 吏, 史 and 事 all evolved from the same character, thus probably share the similar pronounciation in ancient times. 吏's entirely different pronounciation is likely a result of [训读](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%A8%93%E8%AE%80), where the pronouciation and the glyph of a character mismatch. Nowadays 训读 usually refers to this phenonmenon in Japanese, but it did happen in Chinese as well. Also see [文白异读](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%96%87%E7%99%BD%E5%BC%82%E8%AF%BB)（[Literary and colloquial readings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literary_and_colloquial_readings_of_Chinese_characters)）

Comment: a related explanation:  The characters 史 (history), 吏 (government official), 使 (cause; use; instruct), and 事 (matter; work; affair) are all etymologically related and all derive from the same ancient character, depicting a hand (又) holding a container for writing utensils. 事 and 史 were originally written the same, but later an extra mark was added to distinguish them. (https://www.dong-chinese.com/wiki/%E4%BA%8B)

Answer (score 1):

Words that look similar do not always share the same origin or phonic element.

e.g.

人 and 入; 全 and 金; 赤 and 亦

木，林， and 森 all sound different from each other

Sometimes, two different parts from two different characters would evolve into the same form